# Jest mocking non-default child component in Typescript returns an error

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

When using Jest to mock a child component and using Typescript, the test returns an error.

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:
Create a child component:

```
export const MyChildComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Something there.</span>
    </>
  );
};
```

then use it in a parent component

```
import { MyChildComponent } from './components/MyChildComponent';

export const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Something here.</span>
      <MyChildComponent />
    </>
  );
};
```

then write a test:

```
jest.mock('./components/MyChildComponent', () => () => 'mocked');
describe('My parent component', () => {
  it('renders main span', () => {
    render(<ParentComponent>);
  };
};
```

This returns an errot:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

### Expected behavior

The test should not return an error and pass/fail based on test implementation.

This is related to https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2984 which was closed 3 days ago and that might be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that the issue is that my child component is not exported as `default`. And given my `tsconfig.js` (created via the create-react-app bootstrapper), I had to change how I export my child component:

```
const MyChildComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Something there.</span>
    </>
  );
};
export default MyChildComponent;
```

and remove the `{}` in the import when using it.